# Does OROCRM fits our process?

Tags: workflow, crm, b2b, orocrm

Hey guys we need to realize the following workflow:

Our process looks as following:

We have a customer base with several attributes for each customer like city, type of product, segment and so on.It should be possible for the manager to choose the correct customers according to the attributes (e.g. all customer from city x and type y of product) and assign this customers to a marketing process.

The marketing process would look like:

User gets a notification call customer x

User is being asked how the call was and the user can choose from several categories (no interest, slight interest, wrong number, ....)

The logic behind what happens afterwards is in the program

[THE WORKFLOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHQNn.jpg)

In short:
Defining the customer range -> putting them into a process -> user gives a response in a pre defined way to the task he performed -> the process goes on

Thank you for your response!

PS. There is no need for VOIP integration.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here; please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, OroCRM is flexible enough to handle completely custom workflows. Simple workflows, like the one that you described can even be configured from the user interface, without custom development.

> We have a customer base with several attributes for each customer like the city, type of product, segment, and so on.

Depending on the needs, you can use one of the existing OroCRM entities as a base customer (e.g. [a Lead](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/sales/leads/#user-guide-system-channel-entities-leads) or [an Account](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/customers/accounts/) entity) and add all the needed extra fields using [the entity management](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/entities/manage-entity-fields/). Or you can create a completely new [custom entity](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/entities/create-entities/) with all the fields and relations to use it as a base customer.

> It should be possible for the manager to choose the correct customers according to the attributes (e.g. all customers from city x and type y of product)

You can use OroCRM [data grids](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/getting-started/navigation/record-tables/#doc-grids-actions-filters) to filter base customers by attributes and even create a [custom grid view](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/getting-started/navigation/record-tables/#create-saved-table-views-grid-views) with predefined filters to reuse it later. The [flexible reporting system](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/reports-segments/reports/custom-reports/) also may be helpful here.

> and assign these customers to the marketing process.

In OroCRM they are called [workflows](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/workflows/). There are a few predefined workflows, and you can create a completely custom within the user interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It helped me already a lot! Do I understand correctly that the community edition would be enough to solve our workflow?

Comment: It depends. All the above requirements are covered with the community edition. But if you have large data sets, need some additional features, like multiple organizations, LDAP integration, etc. or want to have customer support, then, please check the editions comparison: https://oroinc.com/orocrm/orocrm-enterprise-and-community/